# Perl XS Memory Handling of Strings

Tags: perl, memory-leaks, xs

I have an XSUB like this:

```
char *
string4()
CODE:
    char *str = strdup("Hello World4");
    int len = strlen(str) + 1;
    New(0, RETVAL, len, char);
    Copy(str, RETVAL, len, char);
    free(str);
OUTPUT:
    RETVAL
```

But this shows up as a memory leak, on the New(), in valgrind and if I run it in a loop the resident memory will continue to grow.

I get the same thing if I use this one too:

```
char *
string2()
CODE:
    char *str = strdup("Hello World2");
    RETVAL = str;
OUTPUT:
    RETVAL
```

I'm able to prevent the leak and the increasing memory size by doing:

```
char *
string3()
PPCODE:
    char *str = strdup("Hello World3");
    XPUSHs(sv_2mortal(newSVpv(str, 0)));
    free(str);
```

but the problem with this solution is that when I compile with -Werror I get the following warnings/errors.

```
test.c: In function ‘XS_test_string3’:
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.20/CORE/XSUB.h:175:28: error: unused variable ‘targ’ [-Werror=unused-variable]
 #define dXSTARG SV * const targ = ((PL_op->op_private & OPpENTERSUB_HASTARG) \
                            ^
test.c:270:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘dXSTARG’
  dXSTARG;
  ^
test.c:269:9: error: unused variable ‘RETVAL’ [-Werror=unused-variable]
  char * RETVAL;
```

the c file gets built with an unused RETVAL:

```
XS_EUPXS(XS_test_string3); /* prototype to pass -Wmissing-prototypes */
XS_EUPXS(XS_test_string3)
{
    dVAR; dXSARGS;
    if (items != 0)
       croak_xs_usage(cv,  "");
    PERL_UNUSED_VAR(ax); /* -Wall */
    SP -= items;
    {
    char *  RETVAL;
    dXSTARG;
#line 61 "test.xs"
    char *str = strdup("Hello World3");
    XPUSHs(sv_2mortal(newSVpv(str, 0)));
    free(str);
#line 276 "test.c"
    PUTBACK;
    return;
    }
}
```

So is there a better way to handle the returning of allocated strings in XS? Is there a way to return the string using RETVAL and free the memory? I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Among other problems<sup>[1]</sup>, your first snippet allocates memory using `New`, but never deallocates it.

Among other problems, your second snippet allocates memory using `strdup`, but never deallocates it.

The underlying problem with your third snippet is that you claim the XS function returns a value and it doesn't. That value would have been assigned to [`RETVAL`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlxs.html#The-RETVAL-Variable), which is automatically created for that very purpose. The variable won't be created if you correctly specify that you don't return anything.

```
void
string3()
PREINIT:
    char *str;
PPCODE:
    str = strdup("Hello World3");
    XPUSHs(sv_2mortal(newSVpv(str, 0)));
    free(str);
```

or just

```
void
string3()
PPCODE:
    XPUSHs(sv_2mortal(newSVpv("Hello World3", 0)));
```

Note that I moved your declarations out of `PPCODE`. In C, declarations can't appear after non-declarations, and the code in `PPCODE` can appear after non-declarations (depending on the options used to build Perl). Declarations belong in `PREINIT`. You could also use curlies around the code in `PPCODE`.

---

1. One of them is the use of `New`. You shoudln't be using `New`. `New` was deprecated in favour of `Newx` ages ago. `New` hasn't even been in the documentation for as long as I can remember.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. In the seconds case, what would be the proper method of free'ing the memory?

Comment: @gaijin In the second example, you can only free the memory in a custom [typemap](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlxstypemap.html) entry.